# JFrame stop popping with .jar

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jar, jframe

Using NetBeans, I developed a program that uses several `JFrame`s to display information.
Starting it from NetBeans works perfectly, but with the auto-generated `.jar`, actions that should open a new `JFrame` seem not to work.

Here's a general example of how I open a new `JFrame`

```
public class MyFrame extends JFrame {
    ...
}

public class OtherFrame extends JFrame {

    void showFrame() {
        new MyFrame().setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: please this example talking about nothing, for better help sooner edit your post with http://sscce.org/

Comment: @mKorbel kinda hard, since I don't know where the problem is, and the code I'm showing is what I do to show my frames, nothing less nothing more

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "actions"? Are you saying an attempt to run the jar doesn't run the program at all (no GUI appears)? Or that you can run it and the GUI appears, but your not getting the expected behavior? If your jar isn't runnable, it needs a proper manifest file. Make sure your exporting the jar correctly in NetBeans. If the GUI appears, then it's a problem with your code, not NetBeans.

Comment: .jar starts and shows the first frame (connection to a server). When the connection is completed (and it works, tested it), the first frame closes and another should open, but this new frame doesn't appear.

Comment: Is an exception thrown? If you double-clicked the JAR to run it, you wouldn't be able to tell.

Answer (score -1):

Is it even possible in Java to have 2 JFrames open at once?  I'm not saying it isn't - I've never tried.  But what are you tyrying to accomplish?  Having an application take up more than one JFrame is a bad practice.  You should be able to follow the rule one app one Jframe for just about any conceivable app.

Comment: Application is a multiuser chat, and for now every chat has its own frame.

Comment: That is a strange rule. There are various situations where applications could utilize more than one top level window. In fact it is extremly helpful for multimonitor setups, especially when the monitors are different in size and resolution (e.g. laptop and external monitor or projector).